# What is wrong about this code? I can't test variable called number if it's a letter

Tags: c++, c

Can someone help me understand what is wrong with my code. Everything goes fine until p pointer brings on the allocated memory a letter instead of a number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int key;
    int c = 0;
    int number;
    int coins;
    int coins2;
    char answear;
    int n;
    int* p;
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("D://coins.txt", "r");
    PAR2: coins = 100;
    if (!fp) // daca fp nu exista;
    {
        printf("No previous data!.\n");
    }
    if (!feof(fp)) // the condition to be read line by line from the txt file.
    {
        printf("Taking values:\n");
        fscanf(fp, "%d", & c); //reading values from the savegame.
        coins = c; //getting coins from the savegame.
    }
    fclose(fp);
    for (n = 1; n > 0;) //infinite loop
    {
        if (coins <= 0) //if running out of coins
        {
            PAR4: printf("Sorry but you have no dollars left. Try again Y/N?\n");
            PAR3: answear = getch();
            switch (answear) //testing answear
            {
            case 'Y':
                {
                    goto PAR2; //give 100
                }
            case 'y':
                {
                    goto PAR2; //give 100
                }
            case 'N':
                {
                    exit(1);
                }
            case 'n':
                {
                    exit(1);
                }
            default: //if the answear if undifined
                {
                    printf("Not an option. Answear only with Y/N!\n");
                    goto PAR3;
                }
            }
        }
        PAR1: printf("You have: %d$\n", coins);
        printf("\nEnter your number! WARNING: it must be between 1 and 5 only.\n");
        p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); //memory for number variable
        scanf("%d", p); //take the number
        if (*p > 0 && *p < 6) //I need the number to be between 1 and 5
        {
            printf("Your number is: %d\n", number);
            showing the chosen number
            key = (rand() % 5) + 1; //generating a random key
            printf("The extracted number is: %d\n", key);
            if (key == number)
                if the key is guessed {
                printf("Congratulations! You have won 10$.\n");
                coins2 = coins + 10;
            } else {
                printf("You are not so lucky this time!\n");
                coins2 = coins - 10;
            }
            coins = coins2;
            printf("Rotate again? Y/N!\n");
            play again ?
                PAR5 : answear = getch();
            switch (answear) //test the answear
            {
            case 'Y':
                {
                    system("cls"); //clear screen
                    goto PAR4; //going to the starting of the loop
                }
            case 'y':
                {
                    system("cls");
                    clear screen
                    goto PAR4; //going to the starting of the loop
                }
            case 'N':
                {
                    fp = fopen("D://coins.txt", "w");
                    save the coins
                    fprintf(fp, "%d", coins);
                    fclose(fp);
                    exit(1);
                }
            case 'n':
                {
                    fp = fopen("D://coins.txt", "w"); //save the coins
                    fprintf(fp, "%d", coins);
                    fclose(fp);
                    exit(1);
                }
            default:
                {
                    printf("Not an option. Answear only with Y/N!\n");
                    goto PAR5;
                }
            }
        } else
            printf("Wrong number:\n");
        /*
    Message if a letter or symbol has been entered (this message is shown over and over again, and I don't know why...)
    even if it's infinite loop, the loop it should reset so it should again pass the statements above, but it doesn't. 
    */
        free(p); // free the number.
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your question properly

Comment: And pick a language; this appears to be C. `scanf` returns a negative value if the input doesn't match. Use that.

Comment: `p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); //memory for number variable
        scanf("%d", p);` --> `scanf("%d", &number)` ?   `if(1 != scanf("%d", &number)) while(getchar() != '\n');//if input letter then skip upto newline`

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker negative value when EOF. `0` when doesn't match

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check if you can read data from a file by testing `feof(fp)`.  You have to try a read and check the return value of the reading API: `getchar()` would return `EOF` at end of file, `fgets()` would return `NULL`. `scanf()` would return `EOF`.  The `feof()` function can only be used **after** the end of file has been hit by a reading operation.

Aside from that, your code does not compile, it is at best pseudo code and at worst badly translated basic spaghetti code.

Do not use labels and gotos this way, structure you code with loops and tests, and maybe split some of it into separate functions.